# Rewrite JOIN-query to Subquery / faster variant

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

I have two tables, one called *shots* with 9m rows and one called *holes* with 50k rows.
My DBMS is SQLite.

The goal is to get replace the zero values for `x`, `y`, `z` in *shots* with the returned values from *holes*.
I have the following query that has been running the whole day:

```
UPDATE shots
SET x = h.hole_x,
    y = h.hole_y,
    z = h.hole_z
FROM holes h
LEFT OUTER JOIN shots s
ON h.tournament = s.tournament
   AND h.course = s.course
   AND h.year = s.year
   AND h.round = s.round
   AND h.hole = s.hole
WHERE s.end = 'hole'
   AND s.x = '0.0'
   AND s.y ='0.0'
   AND s.z = '0.0'
   AND h.hole_x != '0.0'
   AND h.hole_y != '0.0'
   AND h.hole_z != '0.0'
```

I was reading [here](https://crate.io/blog/sql-subquery-vs-left-join) that a `Subquery` could be up to 260x faster than the `JOIN`.
How do I rewrite my query so it becomes faster?

Comment: Why are you outer joining? Your criteria makes this an inner join and although inner joins are commutative logically you should be selecting `from shots` probably with with index on `end` depending on its cardinality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you are doing an unnecessary join to `holes` which you must remove.

This is the correct syntax for a join-like `UPDATE` statement in SQLite:

```
UPDATE shots AS s
SET x = h.hole_x,
    y = h.hole_y,
    z = h.hole_z
FROM holes AS h
WHERE h.tournament = s.tournament AND h.course = s.course 
  AND h.year = s.year AND h.round = s.round AND h.hole = s.hole
  AND s.end = 'hole' AND s.x = '0.0' AND s.y = '0.0' AND s.z = '0.0' 
  AND h.hole_x <> '0.0' AND h.hole_y <> '0.0' AND h.hole_z <> '0.0';
```

Also, why do you compare against `'0.0'`?
If the columns `hole_?` are numeric then you should compare them against `0.0` or just `0`.